# Solving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-5)^{n}+2(-3)^{n}+3}{(-4)^{n}+2(-2)^{n}+3}$

Tags: calculus

I got stuck finding the limit of the following equation:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-5)^{n}+2(-3)^{n}+3}{(-4)^{n}+2(-2)^{n}+3}$$

I think that limit is infinity and I thought of looking at the odd and the even sequences. Is there a more algebraic solution?

Comment: Divide numerator & denominator by $5^n$

Comment: I think $(-5)^n$ is a better choice @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

Factor out $(-5)^n$ in the numerator and $(-4)^n$ in the denominator:
$$\frac{(-5)^{n}+2(-3)^{n}+3}{(-4)^{n}+2(-2)^{n}+3}=\Bigl(\frac 54\Bigr)^{\negmedspace n}\,\frac{1+2\,(\frac 35)^n+(-1)^n\frac 3{5^n}}{1+\frac 1{2^{n-1}}+(-1)^n\frac 3{4^n}}.$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: why the limit of $\frac{1+2\,(\frac 35)^n+(-1)^n\frac 3{5^n}}{1+\frac 1{2^{n-1}}+(-1)^n\frac 3{4^n}}$ is $1$?

Comment: Because all terms with an exponent $n$ tend to $0$.